# How to prevent Thymeleaf Template Engine read path URL Get Mapping as a template engine name in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a controller get mapping which read path variable to return object from repository, and return template engine name using Thymeleaf to show it, and it works well in localhost with postman and browser:

```
@Controller
public class InvoiceFormController {

  @Autowired
  InvoiceDetailRepository invoiceDetailRepository;

  @Autowired
  InvoiceService invoiceService;

  @GetMapping("/supermarket/invoice/{id}")
  public String getInvoiceView(@PathVariable("id") UUID id, Model model) {
    InvoiceDetail invoiceDetail = invoiceDetailRepository.getInvoiceDetailById(id);
    if(invoiceDetail == null) {
      return invoiceService.showError(model);
    }
    return invoiceService.showDetail(invoiceDetail, model);
  }
}
```

this is the service:

```
@Service
public class InvoiceService {

    public Spring showDetail(InvoiceDetail invoiceDetail, Model model) {
      model.addAttribute("invoiceDetail", invoiceDetail);
      return "invoicePage";
    }

    public Spring showError(Model model) {
      model.addAttribute("error", "not found");
      return "errorPage";
    }
}
```

But, when I creating the unit test, it always became error, because the path url get mapping always read by Spring Boot as template engine name:

```
ERROR org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine -[THYMELEAF][main] Exception processing template "supermarket/invoice/d5afd278-db7c-4482-b992-c7440b522067": Error resolving template [supermarket/invoice/d5afd278-db7c-4482-b992-c7440b522067], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template [supermarket/invoice/d5afd278-db7c-4482-b992-c7440b522067], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
```

the unit test is looks like this:

```
@WebMvcTest(InvoiceFormController.class)
class InvoiceFormControllerTest {

  @Autowired
  private MockMvc mockMvc;
  @MockBean
  InvoiceDetailRepository invoiceDetailRepository;
  @MockBean
  InvoiceService invoiceService;
  @Mock
  Model model;

  @Test
  void testViewSuccess() throws Exception {

    InvoiceDetail invoiceDetail = InvoiceDetail.builder().id(UUID.fromString("d5afd278-db7c-4482-b992-c7440b522068").build();

    UUID id = UUID.fromString("d5afd278-db7c-4482-b992-c7440b522068");

    Mockito.when(invoiceDetailRepository.getInvoiceDetailById(id))
            .thenReturn(invoiceDetail);

    Mockito.when(invoiceService.showDetail(invoiceDetail, model))
            .thenReturn("invoicePage");

    mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/supermarket/invoice/"+"d5afd278-db7c-4482-b992-c7440b522068"))
            .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk());
            .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.view().name("invoicePage"));
}
```

Comment: Add SpringBootTest annotation on class level.

Comment: Add configuration like initialization of MockMvc as in this tutorial https://www.baeldung.com/integration-testing-in-spring.

Comment: thank you for your answer @SelvakumarAnushan, i have tried your recommendation but the error still same. ERROR org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine -[THYMELEAF][main] Exception processing template. the URL path of controller read as template name instead of URL path for get mapping

Comment: Would you have a reproducable example of this available? Because I don't see anything wrong at first sight. You should remove `@Mock Model model`, but I don't think that will help fix the issue.

Comment: @WimDeblauwe I apologize because the code I provided is not complete, now I have edited the code. Actually, the unit test work successfully when I add model.AddAttribute directly under the controller, but I want it placed in a different service separately

Comment: Try to replace `Mockito.when(invoiceService.showDetail(invoiceDetail, model)).thenReturn("invoicePage");` with `Mockito.when(invoiceService.showDetail(eq(invoiceDetail), any(Model.class))).thenReturn("invoicePage");` and remove the `@Mock Model model` field.